# data truncation error on null field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am cleaning my db of obsolete values, and I want to set a column is_promotion to null :

```
update my_table 
set    is_promotion = null 
where  is_promotion = 0
```

And I have this error

> Data Truncation error occurred on a write  of column 0Data was 0 bytes long and 0 bytes were transferred.

Note that my_table have this structure for my column is_promotion, so it should be nullable :

```
  `is_promotion` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Please note that I saw some posts about data truncation, but all of them were because column wasnt formatted for the provided value, in my case my column is nullable

Comment: try using `WHERE is_promotion = '0'`. I mean, you posted that it's a varchar

Comment: Damn my bad! well seen. Can you post an answer and I validate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `is_promotion` is a `varchar`, so you should use:

```
WHERE is_promotion = '0'
```